# Can I permit geolocation for unsecured origins for development purposes?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ssl, geolocation, homestead

I'm trying to develop a web app that uses javascript's geolocation functions. Since version 50, [Google Chrome has blocked access to its geolocation functions for origins not using HTTPS](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only?hl=en). That's not a problem when I deploy my code to a production environment (which has a valid SSL cert), but for development I'm just using a hosts file entry to preview my code running on a local VM (specifically, Laravel's [Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/homestead)), which obviously doesn't have a valid SSL cert.

Is there a way to configure Google Chrome to permit access to the geolocation functions on my development VM, even though it's an "unsecure origin"? Alternatively, is there any way I can configure Homestead so that Chrome will believe that it's secure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest answer to this question turns out to be that Homestead actually sets up self-signed certificates by default, so accessing your dev code via HTTPS works already, albeit with Chrome issuing an invalid certificate warning. However, if you accept that warning and agree to proceed to the insecure site anyway, **Chrome allows the site to use Geolocation as though it were secure**.

However, if that doesn't take your fancy, there are other options:

### Set up Homestead with valid SSL certs

If you have a production webserver and control of a public domain name, you can use certbot to generate a trusted certificate on that server, and then copy the cert files to your Homestead box to use instead of the self-signed certs it auto-generates.

The disadvantage to this approach is that the certificates certbot generates are only valid for 90 days, so you'll need to repeat this process every three months (or any time you re-provision your Homestead box).

1. Add an A record to your DNS that directs the domain you want to use for development (say `local-dev.yourdomain.com`) to your production server.
2. [Install certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/) on the production server, and run `certbot-auto certonly` to generate a valid cert for `local-dev.yourdomain.com`.
3. Copy the files `/etc/letsencrypt/live/local-dev.yourdomain.com/fullchain.pem` and `/etc/letsencrypt/live/local-dev.yourdomain.com/privkey.pem` from your production server to your Homestead box.
4. Update your Homestead.yaml file to ensure that it directs requests for `local-dev.yourdomain.com` to the correct code directory on the box.
5. On your Homestead box, overwrite the files `/etc/nginx/ssl/local-dev.yourdomain.com.crt` and `/etc/nginx/ssl/local-dev.yourdomain.com.key`with the `fullchain.pem` and `privkey.pem` files (respectively) that you downloaded in step 3.
6. Update the hosts file on your development machine to point `local-dev.yourdomain.com` to 192.168.10.10 (or whatever ip is specified in your Homestead.yaml file).
7. Access your site via `https://local-dev.yourdomain.com` and enjoy that hard-earned green padlock icon.

### Explicitly configure Chrome to treat your (non-https) domain as secure

Chrome has a `--unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure` startup flag that can be used for this purpose, but it requires the use of a distinct user profile (settable via a second flag) in order to work.

From the [Chromium wiki](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins):

> You can run chrome with the --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure="http://example.com" flag (replacing "example.com" with the origin you actually want to test), which will treat that origin as secure for this session. Note that you also need to include the --user-data-dir=/test/only/profile/dir to create a fresh testing profile for the flag to work.

Comment: Note that it will be unsafe to browse the web with that flag on.

Answer (score 0):

With your configuration (modifying hosts file to point the DNS of your domain to your machine), you can create a trusted certificate, using let's encrypt for example.

Just to mention it, http://localhost is considered secure, and chrome has a --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure startup flag as mentioned by @4026 in his answer

Comment: Do you have a link to some documentation for how to create a trusted cert for a VM with let's encrypt? I can only find guides for creating self-signed certs...

Comment: I've read through the certbot documentation, and I'm almost certain that it doesn't support being used in the way that I need. To be clear, my VM: is running on my development PC; is inaccessible to anything other than that PC; only has its domain name from the perspective of that PC because of an entry in its hosts file. Apart from anything else, it seems like being able to create a trusted certificate for what is effectively an arbitrary domain would be wildly insecure.

Comment: https://gethttpsforfree.com/ can help you. You still need to be able to put a file on a public server for the domain you want a certificate of course

Answer (score 0):

For development purposes, I use ngrok. You can get a secure tunnel to localhost. This allows to debug webhooks locally, test mobile apps or APIs with the backend mapped to http or https, really simple to install and use.

[ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) official site